# Can anybody give me an example of how to use ARB_sparse_texture and ARB_sparse_texture2?

Tags: opengl, texture

I am trying to support hardware sparse virtual texture in my little engine but I found that there are almost no examples on the internet. Can anybody provide me with a little example to illustrate the usage of these two extensions? Or at least the necessary steps to make it work?

I have already examined the following documents/links:

Khronos document pages: no code samples

- https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_sparse_texture.txt
- https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_sparse_texture2.txt

g-truc OpenGL samples: I don't see a memory/disk swap in/out process in this simple sample

- https://github.com/g-truc/ogl-samples/blob/master/samples/gl-500-texture-sparse-arb.cpp

software virtual texture: I would like to use the hardware virtual texture technique rather than the software one

- https://studiopixl.com/2022-04-27/sparse-virtual-textures
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MejJL87yNgI&ab_channel=SeanBarrett
- https://ktstephano.github.io/rendering/stratusgfx/svsm
- https://www.renaudpradenc.com/?p=517